# dotnet mongodb driver 2.3 and mapreduce not working

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce, driver

I'm trying to perform a very simple mongodb mapreduce with c# 2.3 driver but i'm getting an exception:

The code is:`

string StringDeConexao = "mongodb://10.0.0.211:27017";

```
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(StringDeConexao);
        var servidor = client.GetDatabase("distribuicoes");
        var collection = servidor.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("processo");
        var mapa = new BsonJavaScript(@"function() {
                        var chave = this.Natureza;
                        var valor = {
                                        this.NumeroDoProcesso,
                                        this.Comarca,
                                        this.Natureza,
                                        this.Classe,
                                        this.Assunto.AssuntoPrincipal,
                                        this.Autor.Nome,
                                        this.Autor.TipoDePessoa,
                                        this.CodigoCnaeAutor,
                                        this.Reu.Nome,
                                        this.Reu.TipoDePessoa,
                                        this.CodigoCnaeReu,
                                        count:1
                                    };
                                    emit(chave, valor);
                                };");
        var reducao = new BsonJavaScript(@"function(chave, valores) {
                            var ObjetoReduzido = {
                                                    Natureza: chave,
                                                    count: 0
                                                   };
                            valores.ForEach(function(valor) {

                                                     ObjetoReduzido.count+= valor.count;
                                                   };
                                                     return Objeto.Reduzido;
                            };");

       var pesquisa = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("Natureza", new BsonRegularExpression("c[ií]vel", "i")); 

        var option = new MongoDB.Driver.MapReduceOptions<BsonDocument, String>();
        option.Filter = pesquisa;
        option.OutputOptions = Inline;


        var result = collection.MapReduce(mapa, reducao, option);`
```

It works on mongodb shell.

Thank's for any help.

Comment: It says "Additional information: Command mapreduce failed: exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .." but i really cant see where there are.

Comment: Could you please post the `mongo shell` version of the mapreduce ? I think the problem here is due to the JSON syntax of `valor`. It requires `key:value` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Your ForEach() is (was) mal-formed and you have (had) trailing semicolons on each of the functions.